# How to get isolcpus kernel parameter working with Precise 12.04 amd64?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, performance

I've been testing this stuff trying to reserve some CPUs in a host with two Intel E5645 but I can't get it working for some reason. Steps I followed:

1. Edit /etc/default/grub and added isolcpus=0,1 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=0,1"`
2. Run update-grub
3. Reboot

After that, cat /proc/cmdline reveals:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=52cfedad-40be-41b9-9f88-c282a7ae3f24 ro quiet splash isolcpus=0,1 vt.handoff=7
```

Tested using stress:

```
apt-get install stress && stress -c 24
```

Monitored using top and pressing 1 to display individual CPU stats. So far no CPUs are isolated from the scheduler and all of them are busted by stress.

```
Cpu0  : 99.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu1  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu2  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu3  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu4  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu5  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu6  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu7  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu8  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu9  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu10 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu11 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu12 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu13 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu14 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu15 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu16 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu17 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu18 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu19 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu20 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu21 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu22 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
Cpu23 :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa
```

Tested the same stuff in CentOS 6 x86_64 and it works as expected.

Searched ubuntu and linux bugs database in launchpad but did not find anything so far.

Is it me being dumb or am I missing something? Hints?

Thanks!

Refs:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt

Answer (score 5):

Disabled SMT (Hyper-Threading) in BIOS, power cycled, tested again with HT off and isolcpus works as expected.

Re-enabled SMT in BIOS, power cycled, still works as expected.

Definitely not the best answer you could expect, but it worked for me nevertheless.

Comment: Are you saying that both reboots gave the same result regardless of the Hyper-Threading settings? In which case, maybe rebooting was the work around(?)

Answer (score 3):

isolcpus only isloate from ceratin user-space activity and will not isolate the CPU from the kernel activity (watchdogs, kworkers, linux stack ...). Moreover, you should not isolate cpu 0 (which has numerous dedicated activities like usb discovery, acpi timer setup, wrmsr/rdmsr dispatching .... which tend to amount to 2% with standard distro where all drivers are enabled by default)

You can verify which processes are running on which cores, by displaying all the threads sorted by core number.

```
ps -aFeL | cut -c 48- | sort -n
```

You also need to verify and modify the affinities in /proc/irq/* , in order to try to change the interrupt affinities.

You might dynamically spare cpus and remove "most" of linux kernel task using cpuset tool.

instead of

```
taskset -c 3-7,11-15 program args
```

try this

```
sudo apt install cpuset
cset set --list
cset shield -c 3-7,11-15
cset set --list
cset shield -e program -- args
```

And then, you can appreciate the difference

```
ps -aFeL | cut -c 48- | sort -n
```

When running these 2 commands

```
cset shield -e stress -- -c 16
stress -c 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `isolcpus` seems (by my testing) to behave differently on AMD and Intel CPUs.

`Kernel: 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit)` on both

`/etc/default/grub` added `isolcpus=2` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line`, similar to the OP. Then `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

- On Intel core i7 dual core with hyperthreading, `ps -eF | grep " 2 "` shows only a very few root-owned processes get started on hyperthread 2 (and they all seem to have /2 after the CMD).
- On AMD quad core without hyperthreading, many root-owned processes get started on core 2 (and most don't have /2 after the CMD).

Is this a bug that will probably get fixed, or a feature?